# WPF Stream Live Video

Tags: c#, wpf, video-streaming

I'm working on an WinForms replacement app in WPF 4.5.

The current WinForms app streams video from a C++ component. The C# WinForms control has this code:

```
public void StartVideoStream(int iCamera)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        delStartVideoStream del = new delStartVideoStream(StartVideoStream);
        Invoke(del, new object[] { iCamera });
    }
    else
    {
        if (!VideoPlaying)
        {
            int iSuccess = ClientComm.StartVideoStream(iCamera, ucVideoPlayer.Handle,
                (ClientComm.streaming_protocols)Properties.Settings.Default.VideoStreamProtocol,
                Properties.Settings.Default.VideoStreamFrameRate);

            if (iSuccess != 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("[ucVideo] Could not play video.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClientComm.SelectVideoStream(iCamera);
        }
        VideoPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

You can see that it passes its handle to the COM component which writes the video directly to it.

The problem is that in WPF controls do not have handles. How can I do this I WPF?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've seen this done is to host a WinForms control inside the WPF control using a HwndHost (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Unfortunately this lands you right back in WinForms territory.

HwndHost is a little involved to cover in a sensible answer, but there's a reasonable tutorial here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2007/10/07/5354351.aspx

You should be able to get some useful pointers from the Vlc.DotNet library (https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet), which does something similar. Based on playing around with that, if you pass the handle of the WPF application window to a COM component the video is likely to overlay the entire window. If, on the other hand, you talk to the COM component from a WinForms component inside the WPF component, you can use the handle of the WinForms component and keep the rest of your window clear of obstruction.